# Pannel doesn't show thunderbird tray icon/indicator

Tags: wingpanel

Pannel doesn't show thunderbird tray icon/indicator even using minimize to tray or firefray add-ons.
How can i fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Could you extend your question? I don't know what do you expect...